# Define variable inside while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

How is

```
while (
  stack.peek() in ops &&
  p(stack.peek()) >= 10
) {
  str += stack.pop();
}
```

rewritten so I call `.peek()` every time the loop runs, but only define it once?

I have thought about

```
const peek = stack.peek();
while (
  peek in ops &&
  p(peek) >= 10
) {
  str += stack.pop();
}
```

but since I modify `stack` with `stack.pop()` inside the while loop, I guess the value of `stack.peek()` is changing every time, so I guess I have to redefine the variable inside the loop, but

```
let peek = stack.peek();
while (
  peek in ops &&
  p(peek) >= 10
) {
  str += stack.pop();
  peek = stack.peek();
}
```

also seems a bit wrong, so should it be something like

```
while (
  let peek = stack.peek() &&
  peek in ops &&
  p(peek) >= 10
) {
  str += stack.pop();
}
```

or

```
for (
  let peek = stack.peek();
  peek in ops && p(peek) >= 10;
  peek = stack.peek()
) {
  str += stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: Well, the second to last example is syntactically incorrect, so go with the `for` loop instead? Not clear to me what the issue is. Use whatever code works?

Comment: @Jamgreen. I gave it a shot. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Jamgreen What do you mean by "but only define it once?" ?

Comment: I'm confused. Does `stack` contain functions? And so `stack.peek()` returns a function? So `peek` is a function? In that case, how can `peek in ops` make sense?

Comment: Sorry for the consuion. I have created `Array.prototype.peek = () => this[this.length - 1]`. Is it bad practice to 'mess' with `Array.prototype`?

Comment: _"Sorry for the consuion. I have created `Array.prototype.peek = () => this[this.length - 1]`. "_ Note, `var stack = [1,2,3]; stack.peek()` returned `3` , here,  using `function` keyword . `Array.prototype.peek = function() { return this[this.length - 1]}` . `var stack = [1,2,3];
Array.prototype.peek = () => this[this.length - 1]; stack.peek()` returned `undefined` using arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `while (true)` with a `break`:

```
while (true) {
  const peek = stack.peek();
  if (!(peek in ops) || p(peek) < 10) break;
  str += stack.pop();
}
```

In theory you could also do:

```
while (
  (peek => peek in ops && p(peek) >= 10)(stack.peek())
) {
  str += stack.pop();
}
```

but that's pretty ugly. It's roughly equivalent to write

```
function pop(stack) {
  const peek = stack.peek();
  return peek in ops && p(peek) >= 10;
}

while(pop(stack)) str += stack.pop();
```

A `for` loop is not a bad idea either, and could be written as:

```
for (let peek; peek = stack.peek(), peek in ops && p(peek) >= 10; ) {
  str += stack.pop();
}
```

which again avoids duplicating the call to `stack.peek()`.

Comment: I did go with the `while (true)` approach :D I changed it to `while (stack.length > 1) { const peek = stack.peek(); if (peek in ops &&
  p(peek) >= 10) { str += stack.pop(); } else { break; } }`.

Comment: @This seems over complicated. The solution is much, much, much, more simple.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge The solutions provided do not appear to be more complicated than the original Question?

Comment: @guest271314 That is a strange justification for replacing simplicity with complexity.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Actually, it doesn't matter that much. However, as I interpreted the OP's question, it was about dealing with the unsatisfying nature of having two calls to `stack.peek()` in the code.

Comment: @guest271314 I believe this is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

> How is
>
> ```
> while (
>   stack.peek() in ops &&
>   p(stack.peek()) >= 10
> ) {
>   str += stack.pop();
> }
> ```
>
> rewritten so I call .peek() every time the loop runs, but only define
>   it once?
>
> Sorry for the consuion. I have created Array.prototype.peek = () =>
>   this[this.length - 1].  Is it bad practice to 'mess' with Array.prototype?

Note,

```
var stack = [1,2,3]; 
stack.peek();
```

returned `3` , here,  using `function` keyword .

```
Array.prototype.peek = function() { return this[this.length - 1]}
```

using arrow function

```
Array.prototype.peek = () => this[this.length - 1]; stack.peek()
```

returned `undefined`

---

You could alternatively use expression `stack.length -1` as condition within `while` loop; e.g.;

```js
var stack = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  n = 0;

while (stack.length - 1 && (peek = stack.pop())) {
  // do stuff
  n += (curr = peek * 10) >= 10 ? curr : n;
  delete curr;
  console.log(`peek:${peek}`);
}

console.log(`n:${n}, peek:${peek}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

At minimum, this should work.

```
var peek = stack.peek();  //Declaration (once) and initialization

while ((peek in ops) && (p(peek) >= 10))
{
  str += stack.pop();
  peek = stack.peek()    //Re-assignment after modifying stack.
}
```

Define a variable before the loop condition, then update the variable as the last statement inside the loop. I'm sure you would have arrived at that solution eventually. :-)

Comment: This answer is the best answer, hands down.